# NativeScript livesync for ios fails when launched

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

If I run the native script with livesync it fails for the iOS emulator but not for andriod.

I created the project with the NativeScript cli `create` command. This is a Angular2 project. I can run the project just fun in the iOS emulator if I run 
`tns run ios --emulator`.  Android is fine as well, but livesync somehow breaks. I haven't been able to find anything specific online.

This issue should have been fixed on the latest version `2.4.2` according to a thread on github.

```
shell.js: internal error
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../loose-envify/cli.js' -> '/Users/user/Desktop/app-sample/platforms/ios/app-sample/app/tns_modules/babel-traverse/node_modules/invariant/node_modules/.bin/loose-envify'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:1054:18)
    at cpdirSyncRecursive (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:76:10)
    at cpdirSyncRecursive (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:73:7)
    at cpdirSyncRecursive (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:73:7)
    at cpdirSyncRecursive (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:73:7)
    at cpdirSyncRecursive (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:73:7)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:183:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object._cp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:157:11)
    at Object.cp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:186:23)
    at TnsModulesCopy.copyDependencyDir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/tools/node-modules/node-modules-dest-copy.js:42:21)
    at _loop_1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/tools/node-modules/node-modules-dest-copy.js:17:20)
    at TnsModulesCopy.copyModules (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/tools/node-modules/node-modules-dest-copy.js:31:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/tools/node-modules/node-modules-builder.js:129:32
    at Function.settle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fibers/future.js:249:26)
```

Comment: check- tns info.
If you are pointing to latest version on core,ios. It should work

Comment: HI @Habeeb thanks for answering. What exactly am i looking for. Am I suppose to be running this in the console. If so I have the latest for all of them.

Comment: `│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information │
│ nativescript     │ 2.4.2           │ 2.4.2          │ Up to date  │
│ tns-core-modules │ 2.4.4           │ 2.4.4          │ Up to date  │
│ tns-android      │ 2.4.1           │ 2.4.1          │ Up to date  │
│ tns-ios          │ 2.4.0           │ 2.4.0          │ Up to date  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to vchimev in a [recent post in the thread here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2267#issuecomment-270158744):

> The issue here is that all `.bin` directories inside `node_modules` should be ignored and should not be copied to `platforms` folder.
>
> A temporary workaround is to remove them manually as follows: `find . -iname .bin | xargs rm -rfv`

Apparently they thought they fixed the whole issue, but it should really be fixed in upcoming version 2.5.0 that should be out this month.

I went a different route for fixing mine last week, but if this way works, it's much simpler.

Comment: It looks like that did the job.  Big high five for your help.